# Lego Set ID for white curved pieces with blue Police stickers?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I got another police set but can't find directions.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo5VH.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

The parts with "Polizei" are from the [7741 Police Helicopter](https://brickset.com/sets/7741-1/Police-Helicopter) set.

Other parts are from the [7286 Prisoner Transport](https://brickset.com/sets/7286-1/Prisoner-Transport) set (parts with "Police" and "03").

The license plate is from the Fire Truck of the [7206 Fire Helicopter](https://brickset.com/sets/7206-1/Fire-Helicopter) set.